# javascript - variable is null when loading html content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header which I use in several pages, so I would like to use jquery to import it into each page so that I don't have to make any changes several times, using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').load("header.html");
});
```

The header loads fine, but the problem is that I have a button within that header which I have assigned to a variable:

```
var headerButton = document.querySelector('.header__header-button')
```

And I have added an event listener to this button in order to execute some code when it's pressed:

```
headerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error in the javascript console:

```
TypeError: headerButton is null page.js:17:1
```

The problem seems to be that the variable is being assigned the value before the Html has loaded, although I am not sure.
 There is nothing wrong with the variable or the EventListener, it all works when the header is within the main file. So, what can I do to solve this?
.. Or, maybe there is a better way to import Html that I am unaware of?

Comment: Have you tried the callback function provided by `load()` ? This callback is called when the load is done

Comment: @HussamAlhassan please upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: @goto1 I did try but it didn't let me since I don't have 15 reputation yet. sorry.

Comment: @HussamAlhassan got it, no worries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(document).ready()` inside of `header.html` as well to make sure your DOM is available before you try to manipulate elements with `JavaScript`.

Here's an example of the page you're trying to load `header.html` into:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html lang="en">
  <head><!-- ... --></head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, inside of your `header.html`, do the following:

```html
<!-- header.html -->
<header>
  <p>This is a header.</p>
  <button id="button" type="button" className="header">
    Header button - click me!
  </button>
</header>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("button was clicked");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here's a working example if you'd like to see a demo:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-thompson-xjhdo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').load("header.html", () => {
        var headerButton = document.querySelector('.header__header-button');
        headerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {});
    });

});
```